# Data entry from Checkbox to Textbox

Tags: excel, userform

I am experimenting with the capabilities of a User Form to assist in Data entry.  I would like to know if there is a specific code that can transfer the Value of a Checkbox to a Text box that is on the same User Form when the box is checked.  Basically, instead of having to type all of the words out, it would be easier to simply check a series of boxes to create the sentence.  I know how to input the Checkbox value into the Excel worksheet but I have yet to figure out how to have that same value entered into a Text Box that would provide a "Preview" of the sentence for editing purposes and then the data can be transferred to the Excel Worksheet once it has been approved in the User Form.  In my attached example that I had created and I have a before and the desired after result of what I am looking to do.

Thank you

JLY Test form:

[image: JLY Test form]

Answer (score 2):

Something like below will do that for you, as I don't know the names of your UserForm or your Checkboxes, you will have to amend as required, also you will have to add the following code to each of the CheckBoxes Click Event:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & " " & CheckBox1.Caption
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

To also remove when checkbox is unchecked, the following code will do that:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & " " & CheckBox1.Caption
    Else
        pos = InStr(UserForm1.TextBox1.Text, CheckBox1.Caption)
        If pos > 0 Then UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = Replace(UserForm1.TextBox1.Text, " " & CheckBox1.Caption, "")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There should be an if/then here to remove the checkbox caption when the checkbox is unchecked

Comment: @tigeravatar, you are right, I've updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Thank you very much!  That code has worked perfectly.

Comment: @EarlBorgert please could you accept my response as an answer if if has helped? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

Though really, you'd be best off using a listbox, much easier and shorter code.  Put your list of items in a worksheet and set that to a dynamic named range so you can edit it and the userform will pick it up on the fly.  Make sure the listbox has a MultiSelect property set to `fmMultiSelectExtended` and the ListStyle property is set to `fmListStyleOption`.  Then you can select multiple entries in the listbox by holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

In this example if have put it in Sheet1 (though can be any sheet, and the sheet can even be hidden), and then set a dynamic named range named `listProperties` to this formula: `=Sheet1!$A$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MAX(2,ROWS(Sheet1!$A:$A)-COUNTBLANK(Sheet1!$A:$A)))`

Then the userform has this code:

```
Private Sub listJewelryProperties_Change()

    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To Me.listJewelryProperties.ListCount - 1
        If Me.listJewelryProperties.Selected(i) = True Then sTemp = sTemp & " " & Me.listJewelryProperties.List(i)
    Next i

    Me.txtPreview.Text = WorksheetFunction.Trim(sTemp)

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.listJewelryProperties.Clear
    Me.listJewelryProperties.List = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("listProperties").Value

End Sub
```

And this is what the results look like:

[image]

**Original Answer Here for Posterity:**

Alternate solution, set all your checkboxes to call a function and pass an argument of their value and caption, then the function will update the textbox.  The reason for using the .Tag property is to avoid removing too much due to duplicates in partial matches for the checkboxes (such as `Ring` and `Ring Band` where just plain Ring can be found within Ring Band, this way it will only remove the Ring entry, and not incorrectly remove both Ring entries)

```
Private Sub chk14ktWhiteGold_Click()
    UpdatePreview Me.chk14ktWhiteGold.Value, Me.chk14ktWhiteGold.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub chkAntique_Click()
    UpdatePreview Me.chkAntique.Value, Me.chkAntique.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub chkArtisinal_Click()
    UpdatePreview Me.chkArtisinal.Value, Me.chkArtisinal.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub chkBand_Click()
    UpdatePreview Me.chkBand.Value, Me.chkBand.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub chkHandCarved_Click()
    UpdatePreview Me.chkHandCarved.Value, Me.chkHandCarved.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub chkHandEtched_Click()
    UpdatePreview Me.chkHandEtched.Value, Me.chkHandEtched.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub chkHandmade_Click()
    UpdatePreview Me.chkHandmade.Value, Me.chkHandmade.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub chkRing_Click()
    UpdatePreview Me.chkRing.Value, Me.chkRing.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub chkRingBand_Click()
    UpdatePreview Me.chkRingBand.Value, Me.chkRingBand.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub chkSterlingSilver_Click()
    UpdatePreview Me.chkSterlingSilver.Value, Me.chkSterlingSilver.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub chkVintage_Click()
    UpdatePreview Me.chkVintage.Value, Me.chkVintage.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub UpdatePreview(ByVal bChkState As Boolean, ByVal arg_sText As String)

    If bChkState = True Then
        Me.txtPreview.Text = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Me.txtPreview.Text & " " & arg_sText)
        If Len(Me.txtPreview.Tag) = 0 Then
            Me.txtPreview.Tag = arg_sText
        Else
            Me.txtPreview.Tag = Me.txtPreview.Tag & "|" & arg_sText
        End If
    Else
        Me.txtPreview.Tag = Replace("|" & Me.txtPreview.Tag & "|", "|" & arg_sText & "|", "|")
        Me.txtPreview.Text = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Replace(Me.txtPreview.Tag, "|", " "))
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Much better solution that mine... I didn't even think about the faults of using `Replace` - upvoted

Comment: Thank you, this is a great alternative!